# Where's the macOS log "Mac Analytic Data" file located in the macOS startup drive?

Tags: console

Where's the macOS log "Mac Analytic Data" file located in the macOS startup drive? .  I can't say beyond 5 days back or so in that log in Console for macOS High Sierra..

Comment: The log files are in /var/log.  The actual "Mac Analytics Data" file does not appear anywhere on my hard drive. They may be created by the console app.

Comment: Did you find the files? I did but they don't seem to be in a greppable format nor in an editable format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click (or control-click) on the log in question in the console.app the one thing in the pop-up menu will be "Reveal in Finder."

That will point you to a whole folder full of log files.